# Attempting to use lambda function in static function (C++)

Tags: c++

why is this code invalid?. I don't know if I am using the lambda sintax correctly, but based on other posts, it looks fine.

```
struct foo{
    static int faa(int x);
};

int foo::faa(int x){
    bool isCon = []() {
       return true;
    };

    return isCon();
}
```

Comment: What is the specific error you're getting?

Comment: a lambda yields an indeterminate type, not a `bool`, use `auto isCon =`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951377/what-is-the-type-of-lambda-when-deduced-with-auto-in-c11

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas have indeterminate type, so you can't know which type will one have. Obviously, the lambda you defined won't be of type bool (it may return a bool, but it's not one), so you would do this instead:

```
struct foo{
    static int faa(int x);
};

int foo::faa(int x){
    auto isCon = []()->bool {
       return true;
    };

    return isCon();
}
```

Here, the `auto` keyword tells the compiler to deduce the type for you. The `->bool` expression tells the compiler that the lambda will return a bool.

However, your `foo::faa()` function returns an int, so a cast may ocurr because your lambda may return a bool (which has nothing to do with the question, but watch out).