# closure as argument and return type in C++

Tags: lambda, callback, closures, c++17, using

I struggle implementing a class method that returns a closure that captures `this` (in the example `Foo::f1`). The idea is to use it as kind of a callback in `Bar`.

A first obstacle is that I did not figure out how to specify the closure type in the `using`statement.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
 public:
  Foo() = default;
  ~Foo() = default;

  // don't know what the correct type specification is
  //using fptr = [](int)->int;
  //using fptr = int operator()(int);
  //using fptr = int (*)();
  typedef int (*fptr)(int);

  fptr f1(void) {
    return [this](int k)->int { return k * this->x_; };
  }

 private:
  int x_ = 2;
};

class Bar {
 public:
  Bar() = default;
  ~Bar() = default;
  void setfun(Foo::fptr f) { f_ =  f; }
  void callfun() {
    std::cout << "result = " << f_(8) << std::endl;
  }
 private:
  Foo::fptr f_;
};


int main(int, char **) {
  Foo foo;
  Bar bar;
  bar.setfun(foo.f1());
  bar.callfun();
  return 0;
}
```

vg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the type of lambda when deduced with "auto" in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951377/what-is-the-type-of-lambda-when-deduced-with-auto-in-c11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark `f1` function as returning `auto`:

```
  auto f1(void) 
  {
    return [this](int k)->int { return k * this->x_; };
  }
```

Then you could make from `Bar` class template, and when instatiating 
use `decltype` to get return type of `f1`:

```
template<class F>
class Bar {
};

Foo foo;
Bar< decltype( std::declval<Foo>().f1() ) > bar;
```

Because you capture `this` to lambda, it is non-stateless lambda which cannot be default-constructible, you cannot just store `F` as normal member variable. 
To avoid this problem you could use smart pointer to store `F`, for example `unique_ptr`:

```
template<class F>
class Bar  {
   void setfun(F f) { f_ =  std::make_unique<F>(f); }
   std::unique_ptr<F> f_;
};
```

The full code is:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo() = default;
  ~Foo() = default;

  auto f1(void) 
  {
    return [this](int k)->int { return k * this->x_; };
  }

 private:
  int x_ = 2;
};

template<class F>
class Bar 
{
 public:
  Bar() = default;
  ~Bar() = default;

   void setfun(F f) { f_ =  std::make_unique<F>(f); }

   void callfun() 
   {
     std::cout << "result = " << (*f_)(8) << std::endl;
   }
 private:
  std::unique_ptr<F> f_;
};


int main(int, char **)  {
  Foo foo;
  Bar< decltype( std::declval<Foo>().f1() ) > bar;

  bar.setfun(foo.f1());
  bar.callfun();
```

[Full demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KxCSnT)