# Does a object stores lambda function have it's own address?

Tags: c++, lambda

Based on the result of this topic

[A lambda which captures no variables (nothing inside the []'s) can be converted into a function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7951438/20448327)

I have written a program like

```
void test1(){}
int main() {
    auto test2 = [](){};
    printf("%p\n%p\n", test1, &test1);
    printf("%p\n%p", test2, &test2);

    return 0;
}
```

the result are

0x561cac7d91a9

0x561cac7d91a9

0x7ffe9e565397

(nil)

on https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/

So the test2 is storing a function pointer to the lambda function?

and my question is that object test2, which stores the lambda data, not have its own address?

I thought this test2 should have its own address.

Comment: `test2` stores a callable object. Its type is a class with an `operator()`. A funciton, much similar to an array, can decay to a pointer, thats why you see the same address in the first two outputs

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I refer to `test1` vs `&test1`. I dont think they can be different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does a object stores lambda function have it's own address?

Yes, like all objects in C++ the variable `test2` also has a unique address. You can see this by printing `&test` uisng `cout` as shown below:

```
int main() {
    auto test2 = [](){};
     
    std::cout << &test2;  //prints address of test2
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3oP71hWbs)

The output of the above modified program is:

```
0x7ffe4d4b5fcf
```